# Flutter: Cant' use widget.variable to access widget variable

Tags: flutter

I can't use `widget.message` inside _MenuStatefulWidgetState, the error said **The getter 'message' isn't defined for the class 'MenuStatefulWidget**.

I think because I'm using a FutureBuilder, and trying to access widget.message inside `builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot)` How can I resolve this?

```
class MenuStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MenuStatefulWidget({Key key, String message}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MenuStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MenuStatefulWidgetState extends State<MenuStatefulWidget> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String storeID =
        Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: true).selectedStoreId;
    String storeMenuFilename = 'store_$storeID.json';

    Future _menuDataFuture = getFile(storeMenuFilename);

    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: _menuDataFuture,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        List<Widget> children;

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          children = [];

          var storeData = snapshot.data;

          Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).setStoreData(storeData);

          var menu = storeData['menu'];
          var itemOption = storeData['option'];

          for (var category in menu) {
            (category as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((key, value) {
              children.add(CategoryWidget(name: key));
              for (var course in value) {
                children.add(LineWidget(course, itemOption));
              }
            });
          }
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          children = <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.error_outline,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 60,
            ),
          ];
        } else {
              if (widget.message != null){
                  children.add(
                    Container(
                      margin: topBottomMargin,
                      child: Text(widget.message,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
              }

          children.add(
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
              child: Center(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
        }


        return Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: children,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a variable named message in your widget and then provide reference to it as follows:

```
class MenuStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String message;

  MenuStatefulWidget({Key key, this.message}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MenuStatefulWidgetState();
}
```

using the above code we declared the variable named "message" in MenuStatefulWidget and it will be assigned the value passed as a param to MenuStatefulWidget. Now you can get value of message using

```
widget.message
```

Comment: what is the advantage of using `widget.message` over 'this.message' ? Where is the use of `widget.variable`  documented in flutter site ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MenuStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String message;

  MenuStatefulWidget({Key key, String message}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MenuStatefulWidgetState();
}
```